# Why does my single part MP3 file fail to upload to AWS S3 due to an InvalidPart multipart file upload error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I have a 121MB MP3 file I am trying to upload to my AWS S3 so I can process it via Amazon Transcribe.

The MP3 file comes from an MP4 file I stripped the audio from using FFmpeg.

When I try to upload the MP3, using the S3 object upload UI in the AWS console, I receive the below error:

`InvalidPart`

`One or more of the specified parts could not be found. the part may not have been uploaded, or the specified entity tag may not match the part's entity tag`

The error makes reference to the MP3 being a multipart file and how the "next" part is missing but it's not a multipart file.

I have re-run the MP4 file through FFmpeg 3 times in case the 1st file was corrupt, but that has not fixed anything.

I have searched a lot on Stackoverflow and have not found a similar case where anyone has uploaded a single 5MB+ file that has received the error I am.

I've also crossed out FFmpeg being the issue by saving the audio using VLC as an MP3 file but receive the exact same error.

What is the issue?

Here's the console in case it helps:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please since you're using the console?

Comment: I am trying to use the online gui s3 bucket upload web page. It is like a simple AWS page where you can select the bucket and select the file to upload.

I did just trying using console and it tells me my file does not exist even though it does indeed exist... but maybe that is part of the issue. Here is the command I used:

[cloudshell-user@ip- ~]$ aws s3 cp C:/speaker/cr.mp3 s3://psdms/

The user-provided path C:/speaker/cr.mp3 does not exist.

Comment: So are you using the CLI or the GUI? What does S3 cp have to do with uploading the file?

Comment: I was attempting to use the GUI but when I saw your comment I tried to use the CLI. I am following the example commands on this page under "Uploading Individual Files to S3": https://adamtheautomator.com/upload-file-to-s3/#Uploading_Individual_Files_to_S3

Comment: Add a screenshot of the error you get in the GUI please - do you have access to the C drive?

Comment: This is a pic of the error from the GUI. Yes I have access to the C drive. https://i.imgur.com/Lp2JUhg.png

Comment: OK - thank you. I think it may be because you had a failed upload previously and you've got incomplete multipart upload parts in your bucket - are you able to delete the bucket or folder and try reuploading again?

Comment: You can't see incomplete parts as they're hidden in the typical GUI so just delete the bucket/folder and try again :)

Comment: Well I made a brand new bucket and received same error. I will search how to delete the old error parts and maybe that will do it.

Comment: If you created a brand new bucket, it won't be that - strange; do you have a stable internet connection? Is the file uploading correctly?

Comment: My connection is very stable and at a good speed. This is so bizarre. The file reaches 100% and seems to upload like normal.

Comment: Use incognito and login again - something must be up in your browser especially if a new bucket doesn't solve it

Comment: It worked using incognito!!! You are my hero, the wind beneath my wings. It must have something to do with one of my security add ons. Thank you so much for your help and time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

121MB is below the [160 GB S3 console single object upload limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html), the [5GB single object upload limit using the REST API / AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/) as well as the [5TB limit on multipart file upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html) so I really can't see the issue.

Considering the file exists & you have a stable internet-connected (no corrupted uploads), you may have incomplete multipart upload parts in your bucket somehow which may be conflicting with the upload for whatever reason so either follow this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws-cloud-financial-management/discovering-and-deleting-incomplete-multipart-uploads-to-lower-amazon-s3-costs/) to remove them and try again or try creating a new folder/bucket and re-uploading again.

You may also have a browser caching issue/extension conflict so try incognito (with extensions disabled) or another browser if re-uploading to another bucket/folder doesn't work.

Alternatively, try the AWS CLI [`s3 cp`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command or a quick "S3 file upload" application in a supported SDK language to make sure that it's not a console UI issue.

Comment: Thank you! These steps helped narrow down what the problem was not and helped identify the issue was with my web browser. I was now able to upload the files with no errors after using an incognito window with all my browser addons turned off. Thank you!

Comment: No worries! Capturing our thinking processes in steps as well as providing links may help others that stumble across the same problem as comments can be glossed over and people go to the answers. You're welcome again :)

Comment: I was having the issue with my Firefox regular browser, using a Chrome instance (that I never use for anything else) solved the issue.

Comment: One addon/extension that causes this issue is ClearURLs. Private browsing, deleting cookies, or using another bucket didn't help.

Comment: @GaëlJ that will be due to caching / history / browser data :) nothing to do with Firefox itself